# how to work with Linux dedi-servers by using KVM?

Tags: kvm

I want to rent some dedi-servers located in offshore datacentres, and they come with root access, but to install my own applications and web server software on them, they offer something called KVM.
What is KVM, and how should I use it?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=kvm

Answer (score 0):

KVM could either be "Keyboard, Video, Mouse" or "Kernel Virtual Machine" (a form of virtualization). It's difficult to tell which from the context of your question. In either case, if it's a dedicated server, you don't need either one to install your own software, you can simply install your software normally on the server.

Comment: the database stuff says it's the first one : "keyboard,video,mouse"       there are operating systems like "whonix" that can't be installed easily by simply an SSH command, that's why i need KVM,                                      do you know if it's possible to install such big softwares using KVM?

Comment: If you're asking that question, you need a lot more experience before you start trying to mess with remote servers.

Comment: what experience do i need? unix administration? with KVM, is it as easy as my working with my own computer? provided that they offer keyboard, video and mouse?